# How to package multiple Spring-boot jar in one jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

There are two spring-boot project like after:

```
service_one
service_two
```

they all can run success alone.

Now I had changed this way, I use `service_all` project to manage which services should run: such as jvm properties. The final project like after

```
pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>service_all</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>service_all</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>service_one</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>service_two</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
// Java class in service_all


@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        /**
         * Common
         */
        ConfigurableApplicationContext commonContext =
                new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
        log.info(commonContext.getId() + " isActive: " + commonContext.isActive());

        /**
         * service_one
         */
        if (commonContext.getEnvironment().containsProperty("service_one")) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext oneContext =
                    new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceOneApplication.class)
                            .parent(commonContext)
                            .sources(RefreshScope.class).run(args);
            log.info(configContext.getId() + " isActive: " + oneContext.isActive());
        }

        /**
         * service_two
         */
        if (commonContext.getEnvironment().containsProperty("service_two")) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext twoContext =
                    new SpringApplicationBuilder(ServiceTwoApplication.class).parent(commonContext)
                            .sources(RefreshScope.class).run(args);
            log.info(adminContext.getId() + " isActive: " + twoContext.isActive());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can't package the `service_one` and `service_two` lib in `service_all` jar's lib.

So how can I resolve this?

PS:

- 1. I can't change `service_one` and `service_two` anything, only can use like a dependency;
- 2. I can't use maven parent;

Comment: Did you try adding the second project in the deployment assembly of first and then creating a jar?

Comment: sorry, I can't change the `service_one` and `service_two` any thing, exclude the 
running properties.

Comment: This seems like a problem you solve outside of the java code, i.e: by changing your deployment scripts on your target machine. I know your hammer is Java, but not every nail requires JVM solutions.